# How to see request generated by wsdl2java code?

Tags: java, soap, apache-axis

I using a stub generated by wsld2java:

> ServicesStub.ResponseMessage resp = stub.processService(rm);

Also Rampart module  is engaged which includes a security header.
How can I see the complete XML request which gets send to the server?

Comment: which tool/ide you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or if you don't want to be tied to Eclipse use TCPMON  http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/

You basically redirect traffic through TCPMON and you view exactly what HTML actions happen between your outgoing webservices call (Either REST or SOAP) and you can diagnose, very useful for when SOAP faults do not properly translate to Java with useful error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has a build in tcp/monitor tool - netbeans something similar. Also possible is a normal network monitor tool like shark or a web proxy build for debugging purpose.